# Owl carousel wont autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Popular question but all answers so far on SO didnt help me. I tried changing `autoplay` and `autoPlay`.
The interesting thing is that when you click first on the arrow to get the slider moving, then after a first click the "play" runs correctly, just the first run never happens, slider is stuck. How to make the slider do the first move?

```js
 //#main-slider
    $(function() {
        $('#main-slider .carousel').carousel({
   autoPlay: true,
   interval: 3000,
            cycle: true,
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
<section id="main-slider" class="root-sec scroll-section no-margin">
        <div class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
```

Answer (score 0):

change $('#main-slider .carousel') to $('#main-slider')

Comment: set autoPlay to 1000 instead of true

Comment: here is an example if you still need help http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/2/